# MS Excel - Filter on One item, not if it has both

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an excel worksheet that contains names a list of credit card or reimbursable transaction type per name. The name can be listed multiple times. I just want to filter on names that have reimbursable only...so they do not also have a credit card transaction type tied to their name.

```
Example:

|Name  |Transaction Type
|------+----------------
|Bob   |Credit Card
|Bob   |Reimbursable
|Frank |Credit Card
|Harry |Reimbursable
|Bill  |Credit Card
|Bill  |Reimbursable
```

In the example above I would only want to show Harry since he was the only one in that list that had only a reimbursable transaction type.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Pivot table of your data.[Pivot table video](https://youtu.be/IaOtCWxx3xU?t=1m7s)
For your sample data, I have created a Pivot table like this
[image: sample data pivot]

These is how I made the setup
[image: pivot setting]

As you can see only the name `Harry` has `Reimbursable` listed against the name Harry.
There might be other easier or more straight forward ways to do this.
But I would do it this way for simplicity....